# Comparing dates in C with (Using time.h library)

Tags: c, compare, date

hi there i can compare people birthday in format YYYY-MM-DD with string (strcmp) functions. but i need compare todays date with person's birthday to display if his/her birthday is in 7 days or not_?. i searched "time.h" library but couldn't managed it. i appreciated if you can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `difftime` on the `time_t` values and compare against the number of seconds in a week...

Comment: so how can i convert the string for example "2010-11-10" in a time_t variable for compare todays date.and i am also read the person's birthday string from a file

Comment: You can load the values into the fields of a `struct tm` and then use `mktime` to get a `time_t` value. Just be sure all the unused fields are cleared to 0.

Comment: well friend i guess this mktime will show which day of this person was born. but i need if person's birthday is near within 7 days when program is executed.

Answer (score 3):

The following sample program converts a given string on the argument line to the number of days.
Example output:

```
% ./nd 2011-06-18 1971-02-10 invalid 2010invalid
38 days
-14699 days
2147483647 days
2147483647 days
```

Edit: Decided that -1 is not a nice failure indicator so using INX_MAX instead.

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONE_DAY (24 * 3600)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;

        if( argc < 2 )
                return (64); // EX_USAGE

        for( i=1; i < argc; i++ )
        {
                time_t res;

                res = num_days(argv[i]);
                printf("%d days\n", res);
        }

        return(0);
}

int num_days(const char *date)
{
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        struct tm tmp;
        double res;

        memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
        if( strptime(date, "%F", &tmp) == NULL )
                return INT_MAX;

        res = difftime(mktime(&tmp), now);
        return (int)(res / ONE_DAY);
}
```

Comment: dude what have you done :D. what is library "#include <sys/param.h>" i had never used it. and why we use memset_?. i try "2010-11-25" convert this string to a time_h variable and compare the result with now. so if the result is smaller or equal than 7 than the output will "his birthday is in nearly 7 days"

and what "int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;

        if( argc < 2 )
                return (64); // EX_USAGE" 
is this a control mechanism for program execution_?

Comment: sys/param.h contains parameters for system. Among others it defines INT_MAX which is the maximum value an integer type can keep. It also defines for example MAXPATHLEN which is the maximum length a path can have. And yes, if the result of num_days is > 0 and < =7 then you can say "User has a birthday within a week!" Oh and I use memset, cause strptime only fills parts of struct tm that are specified in the format string, so memset makes sure the undefined parts are now defined to 0.

Comment: well i only copy paste the code for testing and it gives an error which says "newfile.c:37:40: warning: comparison between pointer and integer" for the line "if( strptime(date, "%F", &tmp) == NULL )"_?.

Comment: Either you did not include <time.h> or on your system time.h is not defined in time.h. Consult the strptime manpage on your system.

Comment: int main( )
{
    char buff[11];
    char birth[11]="2011-05-15";
    
    int res;
    
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d\n", localtime(&now));
             
             res = difftime(mktime(birth), now);
    
    printf("%d", res);
    
   return 0;
}

well with this code i can compare the strings "buff" and "birth". buff gets the current time as a string. i can manage this part bur res variable always show 0.

Comment: i guess i must convert the string "birth" to a "struct tm" and then i must send it to mktime() which send in difftime.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `strptime` function for converting the string to a `struct tm`. It is part of Posix, but not the C standard.
http://www.cs.potsdam.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?3+strptime has an example for how to use `strptime`.

You then want to add 7 to the `tm_mday` field, convert the result to a `time_t` (with `mktime`), and then compare that to the current time (from `time(NULL)`), so see if the input date is within the next week.

It is not portable, according to the C standard, to do arithmetic on `time_t` values, which is why you should modify the `struct tm` fields instead. Likewise, you need to do the comparison with current time using `difftime`.

Answer (score 1):

Populate a struct tm with the birthdate and convert that to a time_t.

Get the current time_t using time().

One week is 86400*7 seconds.

Check the difference between the birthdate time_t and the current time_t.

Comment: so how can i convert the string for example "2010-11-10" in a time_t variable for compare todays date. and i am also read the person's birthday string from a file.